# How to inject into dom <object></object> and have it render/load?

Tags: jquery

I am successfully inserting the html into the element without issue via jQuery. The issue is the object never renders/plays/show. Here is my code:

```
<script>
player='<object id="myPlayer" class="myPlayer">';
player+='<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /></object>';
$("#player").append(player);
</script>
<div id="player"></div>
```

The result of this code is correct with the insertion of the html  element however it will never render.

How can I insert an  and have it render as it would if you loaded the page with the object not being inserted via jQuery?

Comment: Well, what it references? `<object data=? classid=?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try appending the object after the `div#player` is loaded (or in a ready/ondomload handler). I'm betting that your script is run before `div#player` loads which is why it doesn't show.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   player='<object id="myExperience" class="BrightcoveExperience">';
   player+='<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" /></object>';
   $("#player").append(player); /* or equivalent vanilla js                 
                                 * document.getElementById("player").innerHtml = player;
                                 */

})
</script>
<div id='player'></div>
```

Comment: I am running the function under document.ready currently. It writes the html as yours does above but it is grayed out in firebug and never plays the video.

Comment: @uber_nOOb: I don't see a param for video. Do you have something like <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/> defined?

Answer (score 0):

change inside script:

```
$("#player").html(player);
```

w/o jquery

```
document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = player;
```